# kendo.drawing.drawDOM working slow in IE for export pdf - kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using **kendo** for export the data into pdf. It is taken more than 1.3 minutes for 2000 table row data in **IE11** browser. I have tried jsPDF also but I'm unable to achieve the design which is in kendo grid.

***kendo.drawing.drawDOM*** - This is taken more time to get the large data in html table.

I want to convert html to pdf.

I tried html2cancas but it is generating as image into pdf. It is not proper solution. How to export pdf with kendo grid html design?

```
kendo.drawing.drawDOM(angular.element(self.options.placeholder), {
                  avoidLinks: true
                }).then(function(group) {
                  logger.info(self.options.filename);
                  var downloadUrl = 'url here';
                  var callback = function() {
                    logger.info("Pdf Download done!");
                    }
                  kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, self.options.filename, downloadUrl, callback);
```

Comment: What version of controls are you using? As of R3 2016 SP1, [drawDOM performance issues on IE claimed to have been addressed](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r3-2016-sp1).

Comment: More time than what? You can't just say "more" without any reference.